# How to you read input file in Visual Studio Code using C programming?

Tags: c, input, file-io, visual-studio-code

In Unix, there's a command that reads input from a file to your c program: pgm < file - Program pgm reads its input from file. Is there an equivalent command that I can use in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This is called an input redirection. It words in DOS as well. You may or may not get that in Visual Studio, since it's an IDE, not a command line.

Answer (score 0):

Using redirection is not a C language feature, it just set the file's data as an input for the stdin stream (which later can be read using C). if you're interested on reading files using C, read about the fopen, fread, fclose functions.